# How to set precision in money data type (PostgreSQL)?

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes

I want to have 4 fraction digits in money datatype column (DB PostgreSQL 10, Windows). Please advice me how to do that? Documentation says: *The fractional precision is determined by the database's lc_monetary setting*. But what exact value I should set up? For example, I want to store $0.4358 instead of $0.44.

Comment: Use numeric instead of money. What you want is possible but difficult and not worthwhile.

Comment: I agree with klin. The `money` data type has a lot of quirks and limitations and - in my opinion - no advantage over `numeric`

Comment: Performance is good advantage, I have lots of data (above 100M rows) and periodically need statistic calculations. I've read many articles "money vs numeric" and decided to use money. At this moment I'm using MS SQL and there are no any problems with money type at all. Want to try PostgreSQL and encountered such disappointing problem. Expected much more flexibility from Postgres.DB.

Comment: Old question, but out of curiosity, what makes you think money is better than numeric from a performance point of view? Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Because in fact money is 8 byte big integer and all CPU calculations with such integer numbers are much faster in comparison with any others types. Moreover, numeric data type will consume more space to store. Of course, this does not matter if you have 10000 rows in table.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't do that with money datatype. The control over the fraction with `lc_monetary` would be such:

```
t=# set lc_monetary TO 'ar_KW.UTF-8';
SET
t=# SELECT '52093.892'::money;
      money
-----------------
 د.ك. 52,093.892
(1 row)
```

so if locale actually means to have more digits, you will have them. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217#Active_codes

Comment: Thank you for example, but this is too strange method... I expected that there is simple "official" way to achieve that. I think I can better use numeric or simple bigint. But with biginteger I have to always correct calculations because of all stored prices are 10000 times higher, that's not good.

Comment: surely numeric would be better. My example was meant to demonstrate how and up to what level you can control precision with `lc_monetary`

Comment: Hi @VaoTsun, is it stilll the case after 4 years or something has changed?